# Trouble with google long lat

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am having a trouble in showing stored variables (lat, lng) from google maps. I am working on a property finder in Greece, and for example this LatLng pair:

```
Lat: 37.448209
Lng: 25.341099699999972
```

Should be near the Mykonos airport. But for a reason unknown to me when I save the coordinates and retrieve them back, google relocates farther into the map, as you can see in this query here: https://maps.google.com/?q=37.448209,25.341099699999972

What is the problem that needs to be solved? My guess is that it relocates to the nearest actual address. I've seen others that have the same interface that once you click on the map it stays on that location and does not relocate.

Comment: Are you using [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/?q=37.448209,25.341099699999972) or the [Google Maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=(37.448209,25.341099699999972)&geocode=1&zoom=18&type=sat)?

Comment: Google Maps API v3. Actually I found that it's the reverse geocode that produces that problem.

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates you are using the reverse geocoder.  If you know the correct coordinates and the address, why are you using the reverse geocoder?

Comment: In the islands there are no addresses and the coordinates chosen, using my old configuration, were being queried by the geocoder. That was the problem that I even saw it on some google implementations. For example the numbers above were sending me to the nearest road. So now I used jquery-ui-addresspicker to correct this, by disabling reverse geocode on my latlng coordinates. The actual problem is on google because outside mainland it doesn't have much data to make precise addresses.

Comment: In conclusion, the geocoder I was using was sending me to the A instead of the green arrow (if you click on the link I provided to the google maps you'll understand).

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps-page may perform 2 base tasks:

1. find a direction
2. find places

when you use the q-parameter, it tries to find a place accociated with the query, it appears there is no place available for the given coordinates, so you get as  result a place near this location